# Creating custom ScalaFX controls

Tags: scala, scalafx

What exactly is the right way to create a custom ScalaFX control? I'm coming from Swing and Scala Swing, where custom components are simply created by extending `Component` or `Panel`. But when I try to extend ScalaFX's `Control`, I can't extend it without a JavaFX `Control` delegate. Should I just create custom ScalaFX components by extending the base JavFX classes instead of the ScalaFX classes?

Comment: FYI, I've added an example to my answer bellow.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I also tried extending the JavaFX control in Scala, so I added that to the examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will want to :

- Create a custom JavaFX control.
- Then optionally create a custom ScalaFX wrapper, on the same model as the default ones. Note that some ScalaFX features (like bindings) should work fine even without a specific ScalaFX wrapper - you can see [some examples here](http://www.scalafx.org/docs/faq_Using_unwrapped_JavaFX_components/).

To create a custom JavaFX control, a first resource to check out is [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/custom_control.htm), but [this blog post](http://programmingwithpassion.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/creating-a-reusable-javafx-custom-control/) goes further. Open source projects like [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) and [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) provide plenty of examples of controls.

Obviously, all those resources show how to do it in Java. I don't see any reason why you couldn't do it in Scala (as long as you use JavaFX classes rather than ScalaFX ones) - but I wasn't able to find any documentation on that, so I guess that it may be safer to create the controls in Java.

**Edit:** I have put up [on github](https://github.com/guilgaly/scalafx-trials/tree/master/custom-controls/) two examples of a simple custom JavaFX control with ScalaFX wrapper class. One version, `YieldingSlider`, is a single Java class that extends the `Slider` class; the other version, `FxmlYieldingSlider`, is basically the same thing, but it shows how to construct a control with an FXML file and a controller class. Note that the JAR file built from this project can be imported in Scene Builder 2.0, so that Scene Builder can use the `<YieldingSlider>` and `<FxmlYieldingSlider>` controls in FXML.

Here's what the simple version looks like.

**JavaFX control:**

```
package customjavafx.scene.control;

import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class YieldingSlider extends Slider {

    public YieldingSlider() {
        addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> lastTimeMousePressed = System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public YieldingSlider(final double min, final double max, final double value) {
        this();
        setMin(min);
        setMax(max);
        setValue(value);
    }

    private long lastTimeMousePressed = 0;

    public boolean mouseWasPressedWithinLast(final long t) {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeMousePressed) <= t;
    }
}
```

**ScalaFX wrapper:**

```
package customscalafx.scene.control

import scala.language.implicitConversions
import customjavafx.scene.{control => jfxsc}
import scalafx.scene.control.Slider

object YieldingSlider {
  implicit def sfxSlider2jfx(v: YieldingSlider) = v.delegate
}

class YieldingSlider(override val delegate: jfxsc.YieldingSlider = new jfxsc.YieldingSlider) extends Slider {

  /** Constructs a Slider control with the specified slider min, max and current value values. */
  def this(min: Double, max: Double, value: Double) {
    this(new jfxsc.YieldingSlider(min, max, value))
  }
}
```

**Can be used in FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import customjavafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <YieldingSlider AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Or in ScalaFX DSL:**

```
package guilgaly.fxtest.mp3player

import customscalafx.scene.control.YieldingSlider

import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene

object TestApp extends JFXApp {
  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    scene = new Scene {
      content = new YieldingSlider
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, please note that if you use it with ScalaFXML, it will not be properly injected in the controller because ScalaFXML looks for classes whose package begins with `scalafx.*` (and expects the corresponding JavaFX class in the same package, but staring with `javafx.*`). However, if you use a package starting in `javafx.*`, you cannot import your control in Scene Builder. My solution was to put an ungly hack in the ScalaFXML code, so that it handles `customscalafx.*` like `scalafx.*`. But that's only a concern when using ScalaFXML.

**Edit 2 :** While I'm at it, here's the same JavaFX control written inScala instead of Java. It works the same, and can be wrapped in a similar ScalaFX wrapper if needed.

```
package customjavafx.scene.control

import javafx.event.EventHandler
import javafx.scene.control.Slider
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent

class ScalaYieldingSlider extends Slider{
  def this(min: Double, max: Double, value: Double) = {
    this()
    setMin(min)
    setMax(max)
    setValue(value)
  }
  // Support for Java 8 SAMs (lambdas) is still experimental in Scala 2.11.
  // I used the old-school anonymous class instead.
  addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler[MouseEvent] {
    def handle(event: MouseEvent): Unit = lastTimeMousePressed = System.currentTimeMillis
  })

  private var lastTimeMousePressed: Long = 0

  def mouseWasPressedWithinLast(t: Long): Boolean =
    (System.currentTimeMillis - lastTimeMousePressed) <= t
}
```